# VBA - Which way is faster/better to copy sheets to new workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm asking this for my reference when I work on a workbook with more sheets in future. For the sake of discussion, say I have a workbook containing 10 sheets that I want to copy to a new workbook except the first sheet, let's name it `Sheets("Hello")`.

First method - copy every sheets 1 by 1 to target workbook, then delete `Sheets("Hello")` in the target workbook:

```
Dim newb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim newfilename As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
newfilename = "Test123"

Set newb = Workbooks.Add
newb.SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & newfilename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
            
For Each sh In wb.Sheets
      sh.Copy After:=newb.Sheets(newb.Sheets.Count)
Next sh
            
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      newb.Sheets("Hello").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Done."
```

Versus

Second method - loop through each sheet positioned after `Sheets("Hello")` and copy 1 by 1 to target workbook

```
Dim indexofHellosheet As Integer, i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
newfilename = "Test123"

Set newb = Workbooks.Add
newb.SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & newfilename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault

indexofHellosheet = wb.Sheets("Hello").Index

For i = indexofHellosheet + 1 To wb.Sheets.Count
      wb.Sheets(i).Copy After:=newb.Sheets(newb.Sheets.Count)
Next i

MsgBox "Done."
```

Which method is faster without drawback (if any)? If there is any other better method, please do share. I'm here to learn. Thanks!)

Comment: Why not test to see what’s the faster approach.

Comment: Note that copying the workbook will copy also the VBA code (in modules or classes) and workbook specific settings (like names or color schemes)

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks for letting me know. Let's say `Sheets("Hello")` has some VBA codes, when it's copied to the new workbook and subsequently deleted, that would be taking slightly longer time I suppose?

Comment: The code of a sheet is copied when you copy a sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy multiple sheets all at once without deleting sheet

```vb
Sub CreateCopyMinusOneSheet()
    Dim i As Long, Sht As Worksheet, arrSht, wb As Workbook
    Const NEW_NAME = "Test123"
    Const REMOVE_SHT = "Hello"
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ReDim arrSht(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count - 1)
    i = 1
    For Each Sht In wb.Worksheets
        If StrComp(Sht.Name, REMOVE_SHT) <> 0 Then
            arrSht(i) = Sht.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Sht
    wb.Sheets(arrSht).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & NEW_NAME & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! A very intuitive way of using `StrComp` to exclude the particular sheet without deleting sheet in target workbook. And also it achieved similar results as Tim Williams' codes. For the benefit of my knowledge, is there a similar function like `StrComp` to compare integer instead? Let's say I want to compare sheet index of the REMOVE_SHT, so it makes it dynamic.

Comment: It's simpler than `StrComp`. Please try `If Sht.Index = Sheets(REMOVE_SHT).Index Then`. Of course, you should make sure there is a sheet named `REMOVE_SHT`, otherwise it raises runtime error.

Comment: I got it worked with `If Sht.Index <> Sheets(REMOVE_SHT).Index Then` to copy the sheets. Thanks! Marked as answer!)

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe: no need to loop when copying sheets

```vb
Sub CreateCopyMinusOneSheet()
    Dim newWb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets.Copy
    Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newWb.Worksheets("Data").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    newWb.SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & newfilename & ".xlsx", _
                 FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested it out and noticed a relatively huge difference (halved the time taken vs codes using For loop). Question: At the step `Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook`, does Excel create a new workbook virtually in the VisualBasic Editor (VBE)?

Comment: Copying the sheets creates a new workbook automatically - we just get a reference to that after the copy is done, since it becomes the Active workbook.